# How to do the following query in Oracle NoSQL

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am planning to use NoSQL Cloud Service as our datastore.  I have question about the MAP data type. Say I have a column “labels” (  `labels  MAP(RECORD(value STRING, contentType STRING))` in table “myTable”, which the “labels” column is  MAP datatype and the value is RECORD data type .

I want to query the table which return all the rows that the key of the “labels” = particular value, what is the sql statement looks like? I tried:

`select  * from myTable where labels.keys($key=‘xxxx’)`

which doesn’t work.

do we need to add the index for the label field in the MAP? any performance improvement? If yes, how to add this index?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following syntax

```
select * from myTable t 
where t.labels.keys() =any "xxx"
```

Your syntax is good if you add exists

```
select * from myTable  t 
where exists t.labels.keys($key= “xxx”)
```

Concerning your question about performance

there will be significant performance improvement.
If you want to index only the field names (keys) of the map,
you create the index like this:

```
create index idx_keys on myTable(labels.keys())
```

If you want to index both they keys and the associated values:

```
create index idx_keys_values 
on myTable(labels.keys(), labels.values())
```